# The path to sshd centos

Tags: centos, sshd

How do I find the path to `sshd`? I need it to configure some stuff but the instructions just say `/path/to/sshd`. Does that mean the `sshd_config` file or something else? is there a default? or terminal command?

-thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On CentOS, `sshd` (the daemon) is usually in `/usr/sbin/sshd`. In any event, you can find out from the RPM:

```
rpm -qil openssh-server | grep sshd
```

Comment: On CentOS 7, If you can't find it at `/etc/init.d/sshd`, then where is it?  I have many other results but which one would be used to start the service (by using `monit`)?